# Character won't stop spinning

Tags: animation, rigging

So I type in #frame into the rotation value so that my friend robot would do some sort of spin dance, however, I kinda want to change it to something different but when I do so it just keeps spinning, even thought I already deleted all the keyframe, is it because I was using Blender 3.4 using blender launcher? or is it something else

here's a video example
https://youtu.be/wnhB62usGbw

Comment: If you enter #frame into an input field then Blender creates a driver for you. The field will get a purple background and the driver controls the value. Right-click it and choose 'Delete Driver' from the context menu to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks it worked!